# Serilog file paths with Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, serilog

I'm fairly new to Versioning my API. I am using ASP.NET 6.0 and Serilog to write to a log file.

Now that I've implemented versioning I want to have v1.0 of the app write to "Logs/V1.0/logfile.json" and v2.0 write to "Logs/v2.0/logfile.json".

I can get the version number "1.0" or "2.0" inside my controllers no problem.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
public class MainController : Controller

    [HttpGet]
    public void MyMethod(ApiVersion version)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("APIVersion: {ApiVersion}", version);
    }
}
```

I can see Serilog will save this "ApiVersion" variable in the log's Properties.

```
"Properties":{
   "ApiVersion":"2.0",
   "RequestPath":"/v2.0/Main/MyMethod",
   ...
```

So how do I put all this together to get Serilog to save the logs in different File locations?

I think it may have something to do with the "Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()" in Program.cs ? I read about various options like .WriteTo.Map or Write.To.Conditional ?

Everything seems to be to do with writing logs of different levels (Informational, Warning, Alert) to different locations though. I also have no idea what best practice for this set up would be.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map).

Below is a working demo, You can refer to it.

Install [`Serilog.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/6.1.1-dev-00295), [`Serilog.Sinks.Map`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Map) and [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning) NuGet Package.

Add `Serilog` in appsetting.json file:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ]
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Map(
                    "ApiVersion",
                    "(None)",
                    (ApiV, wt) =>
                        wt.File($"Your Path\\Logs\\{ApiV}\\logfile.json")
                    )
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
  .Enrich.FromLogContext()
  .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();
//...
```

Controller:

```
[Route("/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiController]
public class MainController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<MainController> _logger;
    public MainController(ILogger<MainController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void MyMethod(ApiVersion version)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("APIVersion: {ApiVersion}", "V"+version);
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Please confirm whether your `basePath` ends with `\\`, if not, then you need to manually add the `\\` symbol:

```
var basePath = "C:\\...Path\\ProjectName";

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Map(
                    "ApiVersion",
                    "(None)",
                    (ApiV, wt) =>
                        wt.File($"{basePath}\\Logs\\{ApiV}\\logfile.json")
                    )
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
  .Enrich.FromLogContext()
  .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I just can't get it to work though hahaha I think it may be to do with the file path I am using. var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory; and then wt.File($"{basePath}Logs\\{ApiV}\\logfile.json")

Comment: I'll have another go tomorrow :)

Comment: Hi @Scottish Smile, I updated the answer based on the code you commented. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had two issues 1) some additional serilog code from my old implimentation elsewhere in program.cs I had to delete 2) Correct spelling of the File Path. You saved me Chen, I was going crazy! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this (I have not add .Map as mentioned above)

```cs
var version = GetVersion();
//Logger configuration
      .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.File(
                    path: Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Logs", version, "Log.log"),
//...rest
```

Comment: Thanks Jazz, but I need two seperate paths (with two seperate files) one for each of the different API versions. Your code would log all versions to the same file?

Comment: I do not see why. You can get the version in the GetVersion() method. You can it via the controller or the attribute vale. Why do you mean that it would be the same value?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't notice the version variable.

Comment: How would GetVersion() work? I have no idea how to actually get the version number inside Program.cs